# java generics and annotations not supported in version 1.3 (travis integration)

Tags: java, maven, generics, annotations, travis-ci

I'm trying to integrate my [github Java/PHP project](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck) with [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org) environment. This is my travis configuration:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - openjdk7
  - oraclejdk7
script: mvn test
```

Below is the output that travis prints:

```
Using worker: bluebox-linux-1.worker.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-9
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck.git tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck
Cloning into 'tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck'...
remote: Counting objects: 458, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (263/263), done.
remote: Total 458 (delta 156), reused 390 (delta 96)
Receiving objects: 100% (458/458), 458.40 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (156/156), done.
$ cd tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck
$ git checkout -qf 47d1ef528f19ad6d01288ac9a3d4c550a79b14f4
$ jdk_switcher use openjdk7
Switching to OpenJDK7 (java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64), JAVA_HOME will be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for apt.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so.
update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_15
$ mvn install --quiet -DskipTests=true
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project wealthy-laughing-duck: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/travis/build/tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck/src/main/java/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/wealthylaughingduck/dao/OutcomeDao.java:[19,8] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
[ERROR] /home/travis/build/tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck/src/main/java/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/wealthylaughingduck/model/Income.java:[12,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
[ERROR] /home/travis/build/tkoomzaaskz/wealthy-laughing-duck/src/main/java/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/wealthylaughingduck/model/User.java:[10,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
```

The output says that I'm using the too old version of java to use annotations and generics. But these are nothing new and they have to be supported somehow (I guess). I've been looking at travis/java docs but found no option about java version (hence I tried to use different jdks). Can anyone point me what should I put into the travis config file?

---

edit:

following @hertzsprung, I ran `mvn help:effective-pom` and it returned following output (in fact, neither `source` nor `target` attribute are note defined for `maven-compiler-plugin` - what can I do about it?):

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2013-03-24T08:15:13                  -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!-- 'com.blogspot.symfony-world:wealthy-laughing-duck:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT'    -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.blogspot.symfony-world</groupId>
  <artifactId>wealthy-laughing-duck</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>wealthy-laughing-duck</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <mergeId>resource-0</mergeId>
        <directory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <mergeId>resource-1</mergeId>
        <directory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/target</directory>
    <finalName>wealthy-laughing-duck-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-beta-8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
      <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/var/www/github/wealthy-laughing-duck/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 24 20:15:13 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my source `pom.xml` content:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.blogspot.symfony-world</groupId>
    <artifactId>wealthy-laughing-duck</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>wealthy-laughing-duck</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with your pom rather than in travis-ci.  Look at the `mvn help:effective-pom` for wealthy-laughing-duck and see if the <source> or <target> elements have been set for the maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: I've provided the output mentioned in your comment. Can you take a look at it and suggest the solution?

Comment: You could try [specifying source and target explicitly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to use 1.7 to see if that helps?

Comment: after some struggling I have finally managed to get it working, thanks to you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please try including the following code in your pom.xml for your Maven build config. I had the same problem as yourself and this seemed to do the trick for me:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.3.2</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <source>1.6</source>
                     <target>1.6</target>
                     <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: That works for me too, but can you tell me why that fixes the issue? thanks.

Comment: @Shubham.Shukla - it was so long ago I completely forgot. I think it's because you need 1.5+ for annotations.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like for some weird reason travis is using source level and target jvm set to jdk 1.3. I think they should keep the maven default (which is 1.5), because this error caught me by surprise and it took some time to fix it, since I don't want to change my project configuration and behaviors according to external tools.

If you want to avoid modifying your pom.xml (which shouldn't be dependent from your continuous integration tool), you can configure travis to compile using approriate source level and target jvm:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7
install: mvn install -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.5 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.5 -DskipTests=true -B
script: mvn test -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.5 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.5 -B
```

This will compile using 1.5 source level and produce bytecode targetted for a 1.5 jvm. You can specify 1.7 in place of 1.5 if you want to target 1.7.