# Why does Travis CI think my code is Java 1.3, and how to fix it?

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I'm trying out Travis CI with a Java project (pretty standard Maven, Spring setup).

Based on Travis docs, this should suffice in the `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: java
```

Travis should notice the project's `pom.xml` and run `mvn test` by default.

However, the Travis build fails, giving me:

```
error: static import declarations are not supported in -source 1.3
```

My sources are Java 1.6. How and where should I tell that to Travis? The [Java project docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/java/) don't mention `-source` option at all. (Also, 1.3 is a bit strange default, isn't it?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602738/java-generics-and-annotations-not-supported-in-version-1-3-travis-integration suggest settings the source/target levels manually, either in the pom or in the travis config file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working by customising `install` and `script` in `.travis.yml` like this:

```
language: java
install: mvn install -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6 -DskipTests=true
script: mvn test -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6
```

...as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721331/56285).

Anyway, I don't know where exactly the Java 1.3 default comes from, but IMHO that should be fixed. Travis [documentation talks of "reasonably good defaults"](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/java/), but in this case that doesn't seem to be true.

**Another option** would be to [add a lengthy piece of Maven XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15603069/56285) to explicitly specify the source &  target levels. Well, personally I'm opposed to the idea of having to do that, just because a CI environment has silly defaults. (Isn't the whole point with Maven to avoid explicitly specifying stuff by using *reasonable* conventions?) With my current `pom.xml` everything works fine locally (e.g. `mvn test`) as well as when deploying on Heroku.

### Update (2015, Java 8)

Just wanted to add that as of 2015, with a **Java 8** codebase, you no longer need such customisations in Maven or Travis config. You get away with the following:

In `pom.xml`, under top-level `<project>`:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

And in `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk8
```

Which is nice. Note that JDK 8 *must* be specified, even when pom.xml sets Java version to 1.8. Travis otherwise defaults to JDK 7.

Comment: In case this was a problem with OpenJDK defaults, I tried only specifying `jdk: oraclejdk7` (without `install` and `script`), but that didn't help.

Comment: The lenghty piece of XML is the maven way. It is relatively cheap when you consider that all maven tools understand this.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you do not explicit set the source and target levels in your maven-compiler-plugin configuration in your pom.xml.

Older versions of Maven then use the javac default *which is Java 1.3 in OpenJDK* (as opposed to 1.5 in Oracle Java).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is certainly related to a [Bug in Maven3 Ubuntu package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976927/2951970), which is currently installed on Travis worker machines.

**Good News:** In next Travis CI build environment, [Maven 3.1.1 will be installed with Apache tarball release](https://github.com/gildegoma/travis-cookbooks/commit/14f0222cc3f6c0a4f207973bae79986b5912653c). This update is planned to be deployed in November 2013...

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll try again later this month to see if it's fixed.